# How to use Keychain with credit card information

Tags: osx-mavericks, keychain

Could you tell me in below:

1. Is it possible to use credit card information in the keychain for
   the payment of Amazon.com?
2. Is it possible to keep personal information in the keychain for the
   shipment address of Amazon.com?
3. Are these encrypted locally without synchronizing with iCloud?

Sincerely,

Comment: The keychain is encrypted locally.  So even if it were synchronized to iCloud it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is there an option not to synchronize?

Comment: I was easily able to find this article which contains your answer http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813